# Multiple Photos in slideshow type display within viewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I am new to Xcode (started a few days ago).

I'm trying to find a way to get a few photos or videos in a display where the user can scroll or tap through as they desire. There will be multiple viewControllers each with a different set of photos.

Is there any existing UI type data types I can just drag and drop to make this work? Or is this out of range of the capabilities for someone not using code specifically.

I know Java, C, C++, MATLAB, etc. but never have toyed with Objective-C until now. Point being, I should be able to follow any logic you can throw at me, but I'm unfamiliar with the GUI and layout of Xcode as a whole.

This is what I currently have.

[image: What I have]

This is what I want. Perhaps with functionality to tap to full screen the image or swipe to go to another image. (This image was made with photosop. I don't actually have the picture file in Xcode because I don't know how)

[image: What I want]

SOLVED: Placed desired images in "Supporting files" content folder inside Xcode. This allowed me to select which photo I want displayed in which ImageView. To fix the proportionality issue where photos in Simulator are far too large, I simply added height and width constraints along with some other centering aspects and got the desired result.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: @Adeel I edited the original post to include screenshots/concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller) where you can display multiple cells with embedded views for your images, and consider segueing between them via a [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller).

Edit: Now that you've added screenshots, I'd recommend using a UICollectionView embedded on your subclass of a UIViewController instead of a UICollectionViewController. This should give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Add UICollectionView in your view and set flow of collection view is horizontal make cell size that you want to keep.